# After removing an employee, then adding a new employee. When listing all the employees save, the new employee does not show up

Tags: c

Need a bit of a help here. Little bit back story, Its been 1 month since I started coding. Started with C Language, now I know until Structure and Arrays. Next week will do pointers. So, that's out of the way, now the Question. Here I'll link my Source Code, the output I want, and the output the program is giving.

This is an Employee record where you can add limited employees, view the employees added, remove them, and update them. A basic Beginner Employee record using C language and No pointers. I did everything correctly except in the end its messing up. You can see from the output I am getting is a bit different from the output I want.

After removing an employee it gets removed, but when I add a new employee after removing an old one, it does not show up when I want to see how many employees are there. You can see from the 2 outputs I provided that everything is same except for the last one when I print out the saved employees. I am not getting what is wrong with my Source Code here.

Is it possible to help me with an explanation and the line of code I'm missing which will make my code work and print the Output I want?

We are using Visual Studio 2017 for our C language (Recommended by my College).
And need to submit the output through pUTTY (Matrix Server).

My Source Code - Can be found from the link given here https://pastebin.com/spLhtrt5 and the Source code is also given here

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 4

struct Emp {
    int id;
    int age;
    double sal;
};

int main (void) {

    int i, option = 0, counter = 0, new = 0, srch, don = 0;
    struct Emp emp[SIZE] = { {0} };

    printf ("---=== EMPLOYEE DATA ===---\n\n");

    do {
        printf ("1. Display Employee Information\n");
        printf ("2. Add Employee\n");
        printf ("3. Update Employee Salary\n");
        printf ("4. Remove Employee\n");
        printf ("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf ("Please select from the above options: ");
        scanf ("%d", &option);
        printf ("\n");

        switch (option) {
        case 0:                // Exit the program

            break;
        case 1:                // Display Employee Data
            // @IN-LAB

            printf ("EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY\n");
            printf ("======  ======= ==========\n");

            // Use "%6d%9d%11.2lf" formatting in a   
            // printf statement to display
            // employee id, age and salary of 
            // all  employees using a loop construct 

            // The loop construct will be run for SIZE times 
            // and will only display Employee data 
            // where the EmployeeID is > 0
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                if (emp[i].id > 0 && emp[i].age > 0 && emp[i].sal > 0) {
                    printf ("%6d%9d%11.2lf\n", emp[i].id, emp[i].age,
                            emp[i].sal);
                }
            }
            printf ("\n");
            break;
        case 2:                // Adding Employee
            // @IN-LAB

            printf ("Adding Employee\n");
            printf ("===============\n");
            if (counter < SIZE) {
                printf ("Enter Employee ID: ");
                scanf ("%d", &emp[new].id);
                printf ("Enter Employee Age: ");
                scanf ("%d", &emp[new].age);
                printf ("Enter Employee Salary: ");
                scanf ("%lf", &emp[new].sal);
                new++;
                counter++;
                printf ("\n");
                break;
            } else {
                printf ("ERROR!!! Maximum Number of Employees Reached\n\n");
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            don = 0;
            printf ("Update Employee Salary\n");
            printf ("======================\n");
            do {
                printf ("Enter Employee ID: ");
                scanf ("%d", &srch);
                for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                    if (emp[i].id == srch) {
                        printf ("The current salary is %.2lf\n", emp[i].sal);
                        printf ("Enter Employee New Salary: ");
                        scanf ("%lf", &emp[i].sal);
                        don = 1;
                        printf ("\n");
                    }

                }

                if (don == 0) {
                    printf ("*** ERROR: Employee ID not found! ***\n");
                }

            } while (don != 1);
            break;
        case 4:
            don = 0;
            printf ("Remove Employee\n");
            printf ("===============\n");
            do {
                printf ("Enter Employee ID: ");
                scanf ("%d", &srch);
                for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                    if (emp[i].id == srch) {
                        printf ("Employee %d will be removed", emp[i].id);
                        emp[i].id = 0;
                        emp[i].age = 0;
                        emp[i].sal = 0;
                        counter--;
                        don = 1;
                        printf ("\n\n");
                    }
                }
                if (don == 0) {
                    printf ("*** ERROR: Employee ID not found! ***\n");
                }

            } while (don != 1);
            break;
        default:
            printf ("ERROR: Incorrect Option: Try Again\n\n");
        }
    } while (option != 0);
    printf ("Exiting Employee Data Program. Good Bye!!!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The Output I want - https://pastebin.com/CcrXibB4 .

The Output I am getting - https://pastebin.com/mmvjBVL9 .

Comment: pastebin deletes the source code after some time... please edit your question and include at least your own code in the question, never do it in pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing an employee doesn't decrement your `new` counter.

Change your code for `case 4:` to this:

```c
don = 0;
printf("Remove Employee\n");
printf("===============\n");
do {
    printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &srch);
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (emp[i].id == srch) {
            printf("Employee %d will be removed", emp[i].id);
            emp[i].id = 0;
            emp[i].age = 0;
            emp[i].sal = 0;
            counter--;
            new--; // This is the important bit
            don = 1;
            printf("\n\n");
        }
    }if (don == 0) {
        printf("*** ERROR: Employee ID not found! ***\n");
    }
} while (don != 1);
break;
```

and it should work.

What your program should do is change the `new` variable to represent the lowest unused spot in the array of employees, by incrementing it upon adding elements and decrementing it upon removing elements.
However you forgot to decrement the index, moving it up indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting the new employee in the position of the index `new`. When you delete after inserting 4 employees new still points to 4, outside the array, therefore your new employee will be written outside the array and never displayed, corrupting also your stack.

Possible solution: when adding a new employee scan the array to find a free spot (for example, find an employee with id == 0 if I understand your logic correctly) and use its position as insertion index.

I have also a couple of general suggestions for what concerns your code:

1. Write small functions, in your case create a function for insertion, one for deletion, etc.
2. Test each function by itself, so you do not need to test everything manually.
3. Then write tests to see how the functions interact with each other
4. Add User interface (your menu, switch case, etc.) only at the end.

Usually this allows faster debugging and if that is not the case, at least you have a way smaller example to post here.

Answer (score 1):

You have a large number of errors in your code. Primarily, do not loop `for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)`, instead, only loop over those array elements that are filled, e.g. `for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)`.

You do not need the variable `new` (and it is a keyword in C++). Just remove it. You should be using `counter` there instead.

You fail to check the return of `scanf` and therefore teeter one slip of a keystroke away from *Undefined Behavior* on ever user input. Always, ALWAYS, ***validate*** all user input by at minimum checking the **return**.

`scanf` can be used, if used correctly. This means **you** are responsible for checking the **return** of `scanf` *every time*. You must handle *three conditions*

1. `(return == EOF)` the user canceled input by generating a manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or on windows <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd>, but see [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10 (early versions)](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/));
2. `(return < expected No. of conversions)` a *matching* or *input* failure occurred. For a *matching* failure you must account for every character left in your input buffer. (scan forward in the input buffer reading and discarding characters until a `'\n'` or `EOF` is found); and finally
3. `(return == expected No. of conversions)` indicating a successful read -- it is then up to you to check whether the input meets any additional criteria (e.g. positive integer, positive floating-point, within a needed range, etc..).

**Note:** after either a *matching failure* or successful read, you should empty the input buffer to ensure is it is prepared for the next user input. With your code try entering `w` (as a missed keystroke for `3`) and see what happens. Further, what if the user enters `"3'"` as his finger skips over the `'` key reaching for <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

So how do you validate every input? In your case, just add another variable `int rtn;` to capture the return of `scanf` each time, and then validate whether the user has canceled input by generating a manual `EOF` or if the return is `0` before continuing, e.g.

```
        rtn = scanf ("%d", &option);    /* always validate scanf return */
        if (rtn == EOF) 
            option = 0;         /* handle EOF by setting exit condition */
        else if (rtn == 0) {    /* otherwise throw error & empty stdin */
            fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
            empty_stdin();  /* always empty stdin after error */
            continue;
        }
```

What is `empty_stdin()`? It is simply a helper-function you write that scans forward in the input-buffer (`stdin`) discarding characters until either a `'\n'` is found (created when the user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>) or `EOF` is encountered, e.g.

```
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

Next, your `case 4:`, `"Remove Employee"` will never work once you stop looping over `SIZE` each time and simply use `counter` like you should. You generally do not want to simply set each removed member to `0`, that leave you without any idea where the next addition should go. Instead, simply loop from the current index where `id` is found to remove to the end of the filled array (`counter`) by copying the next element to the current index in a separate loop, e.g.

```
                    /* only loop over filled struct */
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                        if (emp[i].id == srch) {
                            printf ("Employee %d will be removed", emp[i].id);
                            for (int j = i + 1; j < counter; j++) {
                                emp[j - 1].id = emp[j].id;
                                emp[j - 1].age = emp[j].age;
                                emp[j - 1].sal = emp[j].sal;
                            }
                            counter--;
                            don = 1;
                            printf ("\n\n");
                        }
                    }
```

(**note:** your use of the `don` flag to determine whether the index was found is perfectly fine)

There are dozens of little nits left to clean up. Like:

```
        putchar ('\n'); /* putchar outputs a single-character (not printf) */
```

When you are outputting text, only need to use `printf` if there is a conversion involved requiring one of the `printf` *conversion specifiers*, other wise simply use `puts` (or `fputs` if you no `'\n'` line-ending is desired). Further, you only need a single call to `printf` (or `puts` or `fputs` to output as many lines as you like). You don't need one function call per-line. For example, the following works fine:

```
        fputs ( "\n1. Display Employee Information\n"
                "2. Add Employee\n"
                "3. Update Employee Salary\n"
                "4. Remove Employee\n"
                "0. Exit\n\n"
                "   choice: ", stdout);
```

(**note:** the initial `'\n'` eliminates all your `printf ("\n");` below)

For `case 3:` or `case 4:`, what happens if either of those two cases are chosen from the menu before anything is added to the list? (e.g. when `counter == 0`). You are kinda stuck there aren't you. With any operation that requires data to be present, always validate there is data before you go further. A simple check of `counter` is all that is required, e.g.

```
            case 3:
                don = 0;
                puts (  "Update Employee Salary\n"
                        "======================");
                if (counter == 0) {
                    puts ("(list is empty)");
                    break;
                }
                ...
```

(**note:** the same should apply to `case 1:` as well)

`#define SIZE 4` is a good and proper use of `#define` to define integer constants, but why limit yourself to `4` employees? Make it interesting. Use `128` or `2048`, etc.. At least then you will have a solid medium sized company. Also, since you no longer loop over `SIZE` in every `for` loop, you incur no additional penalty no matter how large the limit is.

From a code factoring standpoint, you should look to making your code more functional and less repetitive by creating functions for your common tasks. Like taking a validating integer input. Handling adding, updating and removing employees, etc. I understand while learning it is helpful to see the code all written sequentially so you are not jumping up and down the page following the logic as control is passed from function to function, but look for repeated areas as you go forward (like `empty_stdin()` in the example) and work to move those common bits of code into functions.

There are probably a number of additional nits I have overlooked mentioning, but if you make the changes outlined above, validate all your inputs, empty any extraneous characters from `stdin` before your next input, etc.. your code will work properly and the interface will be much more robust. A short (well not that short) example making the changes would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 128

struct Emp {
    int id;
    int age;
    double sal;
};

void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int main (void) {

    int i, option = 0, counter = 0, srch, don = 0, rtn;
    struct Emp emp[SIZE] = { {0} };

    puts ("---=== EMPLOYEE DATA ===---\n"); /* no converison, puts if ok */
    do {        /* only 1 output call needed */
        fputs ( "\n1. Display Employee Information\n"
                "2. Add Employee\n"
                "3. Update Employee Salary\n"
                "4. Remove Employee\n"
                "0. Exit\n\n"
                "   choice: ", stdout);
        rtn = scanf ("%d", &option);    /* always validate scanf return */
        if (rtn == EOF) 
            option = 0;         /* handle EOF by setting exit condition */
        else if (rtn == 0) {    /* otherwise throw error & empty stdin */
            fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
            empty_stdin();  /* always empty stdin after error */
            continue;
        }
        putchar ('\n'); /* putchar outputs a single-character */

        switch (option) {
            case 0: break;
            case 1:     // Display Employee Data
                puts (  "EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY\n"
                        "======  ======= ==========");
                if (counter == 0) {
                    puts ("(list is empty)");
                    break;
                }
                /* only loop over counter employees */
                for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                        printf ("%6d%9d%11.2lf\n", emp[i].id, emp[i].age,
                                emp[i].sal);
                break;
            case 2:     // Adding Employee
                puts (  "Adding Employee\n"
                        "===============");
                if (counter < SIZE) {
                    fputs ("Enter Employee ID: ", stdout);
                    rtn = scanf ("%d", &emp[counter].id);   /* save return */
                    if (rtn == EOF) {   /* handle EOF */
                        option = 0;     /* set exit condition */
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (rtn == 0) { /* otherwise matching failure */
                        fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
                        empty_stdin();
                        continue;
                    }

                    fputs ("Enter Employee Age: ", stdout);
                    rtn = scanf ("%d", &emp[counter].age);
                    if (rtn == EOF) { 
                        option = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (rtn == 0) {
                        fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
                        empty_stdin();
                        continue;
                    }
                    fputs ("Enter Employee Salary: ", stdout);
                    rtn = scanf ("%lf", &emp[counter].sal);
                    if (rtn == EOF) { 
                        option = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (rtn == 0) {
                        fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
                        empty_stdin();
                        continue;
                    }
                    counter++;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    printf ("ERROR!!! Max Number of Employees Reached\n\n");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                don = 0;
                puts (  "Update Employee Salary\n"
                        "======================");
                if (counter == 0) {
                    puts ("(list is empty)");
                    break;
                }
                do {
                    fputs ("Enter Employee ID: ", stdout);
                    rtn = scanf ("%d", &srch);  /* save return */
                    if (rtn == EOF) {           /* validate */
                        option = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (rtn == 0) {
                        fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
                        empty_stdin();
                        continue;
                    }
                    /* again, only loop over filled struct */
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                        if (emp[i].id == srch) {
                            printf ("The current salary is %.2lf\n",
                                    emp[i].sal);
                            fputs ("Enter Employee New Salary: ", stdout);
                            rtn = scanf ("%lf", &emp[i].sal);   /* save rtn */
                            if (rtn == EOF) {                   /* validate */
                                option = 0;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (rtn == 0) {
                                fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
                                empty_stdin();
                                continue;
                            }
                            don = 1;
                        }
                    }

                    if (don == 0) {
                        printf ("*** ERROR: Employee ID not found! ***\n");
                    }

                } while (don != 1);
                break;
            case 4:
                don = 0;
                puts (  "Remove Employee\n"
                        "===============\n");
                if (counter == 0) {
                    puts ("(list is empty)");
                    break;
                }
                do {
                    fputs ("Enter Employee ID: ", stdout);
                    rtn = scanf ("%d", &srch);  /* save return */
                    if (rtn == EOF) {           /* validate */
                        option = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (rtn == 0) {
                        fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
                        empty_stdin();
                        continue;
                    }
                    /* only loop over filled struct */
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                        if (emp[i].id == srch) {
                            printf ("Employee %d will be removed", emp[i].id);
                            for (int j = i + 1; j < counter; j++) {
                                emp[j - 1].id = emp[j].id;
                                emp[j - 1].age = emp[j].age;
                                emp[j - 1].sal = emp[j].sal;
                            }
                            counter--;
                            don = 1;
                            printf ("\n\n");
                        }
                    }
                    if (don == 0) {
                        printf ("*** ERROR: Employee ID not found! ***\n");
                    }

                } while (don != 1);
                break;
            default:
                printf ("ERROR: Incorrect Option: Try Again\n\n");
        }
    } while (option != 0);
    puts ("\nExiting Employee Data Program. Good Bye!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

Looks things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Only one word for you, are you a Human?
Learned a LOT of things from your reply. As I said in the question, Its been 1 month since I started coding, Only know till Structures and Arrays, (Dont know about  fputs, empty_stdin, etc) . But after reading your reply, pretty sure I know them now and their work. I learned a lot of things from your reply! 

I already got my answer few minutes back, you can see from the other comments. Thanks for your time and the way you explained. Very much appreciated!

Thanks Again!

Comment: @HelenSummer glad it helps. There is a lot to learn in C. It's not something you learn in a month, a semester, or a year. There is no better language to learn and it will make you a better programmer no matter what language you end up coding in. Last best advice I can give is *Always Compile With Warnings Enabled*. That means add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your compile string for gcc/clang or add `/W3` with VS (`cl.exe`). All compilers provide similar capability. And..... *Do Not Accept Code Until It Compiles Without a Single Warning* `:)`