# Letting user try inputting again after entering incorrect option

Tags: c

So I have some code that generates a set of random numbers. Afterwards, it asks the user if they would like to produce another set of random numbers. The problem I'm having is that I want the user to only input y for yes or n for no, and if they don't input those to options, tell them that is an invalid input and to try again. I cannot figure out how to do this. Here is the code:

```
// C program for generating a
// random number in a given range.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// Generates and prints 'count' random
// numbers in range [lower, upper].
void printRandoms(int lower, int upper,
                            int count) {
    int i;

    printf("\nGenerated Numbers:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int num = (rand() %
        (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
        printf("%d ", num);
    }
}

int main() {
    int lower, upper, count;
    char c='y';

    do {
        printf("Minimum number size:\n");
        scanf("%d", &lower);
        printf("\nMaximum number size:\n");
        scanf("%d", &upper);
        printf("\nAmount of numbers to be generated:\n");
        scanf("%d", &count);

        // Use current time as
        // seed for random generator
        srand(time(0));

        printRandoms(lower, upper, count);

        printf("\n\nGenerate new set? (y/n)\n");
        scanf(" %c",&c);
        printf("\n");
        if (c=='n'){
            exit(0);
        }
        do {
            printf("Please enter valid input!\n");
            scanf(" %c", &c);
            if (c=='n'){
              exit(0);
            }
        } while (c!='y'||c!='n');

    } while(c=='y');

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return***. With `scanf` especially, you must check for `EOF` or less than the requested number of conversions indicating a *matching* or *input* failure. You must further empty any offending characters causing a *matching* failure from the input-stream before your next input, otherwise, the characters causing the failure remain unread, just waiting to bite you again on your next attempted input.

Comment: [Requesting user input in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52471846/requesting-user-input-in-c/52472062#52472062) and [After removing an employee, then adding a new employee. When listing all the employees save,…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614470/after-removing-an-employee-then-adding-a-new-employee-when-listing-all-the-emp/56615133#56615133)

Answer (score 0):

This answers your question, but on a side note, I usually like putting the conditional in the first question so if the user enters zero then the app will quit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// Generates and prints 'count' random
// numbers in range [lower, upper].
void printRandoms(int lower, int upper,
                            int count) {
    int i;

    printf("\nGenerated Numbers:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int num = (rand() %
        (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
        printf("%d ", num);
    }
}

int main() {
    int lower, upper, count;
    char c='y';

    do {
        printf("Minimum number size: ");
        scanf("%d", &lower);
        printf("\nMaximum number size: ");
        scanf("%d", &upper);
        printf("\nAmount of numbers to be generated: ");
        scanf("%d", &count);

        // Use current time as
        // seed for random generator
        srand(time(0));

        printRandoms(lower, upper, count);

        printf("\n\nGenerate new set? (y/n)\n");

        do {
            printf("\t\t==> ");
            scanf(" %c", &c);
            c &= 0x5f;          // convert to uppercase

            if (c=='N') exit(0);
            } while (c != 'Y');

        } while (1);

    return 0;
}
```